# draw box with cells in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to draw a diagram like the attached image. can i get some advice [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There are several possibilities of achieving this, here is one of them based on the `matrix` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,
nodes={fill=red,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1.5cm,
text height=11pt,text depth=3pt,baseline=center},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2}]
\matrix[mymat] (matTL) {
Text1 & Text2 & Text3\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=2cm of matTL] (matTR) {
V1 & V2 & V3\\
};
\matrix[mymat,below=2cm of matTL.west,anchor=west] (matBL) {
Text4 & new & Text5 & Text6\\
};
\draw[-latex] (matTL-1-3) -- (matTR-1-1);
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[-latex] (matBL-1-1) -- (matTL-1-\X);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you may use `shapes.multipart`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,
fill=red,draw,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,text width=1.5cm,text
height=11pt,text depth=3pt,rectangle split horizontal,
rectangle split part align=base}]
\node [my shape=3] (TL)
{Text1\nodepart{two}Text2\nodepart{three}Text3};
\node [my shape=3,right=2cm of TL] (TR)
{V1\nodepart{two}V2\nodepart{three}V3};
\node [my shape=4,below=2cm of TL.west,anchor=west] (BL)
{Text4\nodepart{two}new\nodepart{three}Text5\nodepart{four}Text6};
\draw[-latex] (TL) -- (TR);
\foreach \X in {one,two,three}
{\draw[-latex] (BL.one north) -- (TL.\X\space south);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you your solution. I just a have a little issue with it. the cells is not alined.

Comment: @user2869180 What do you mean by "not aligned"?

Comment: please check the original post. May be because i add cell to be four and not three cells.

Comment: @user2869180 I have fixed that.

Comment: thank you so much. I just accept your solution. You save my day

Comment: please my last question if i add a new node BBL below BL and i add an arrow from BL.two to  BBL, the arrow is drawn from from the up border of BL to the BBL.two so it cut the cell BL.two. How can draw this arrow from the bettom border of BL.two

Comment: @user2869180 You need to use the appropriate anchors, e.g. `\draw[-latex] (BL.two south) --  (BBL.one north);` or 
`\draw[-latex] (BL.two south) to[out=-90,in=90]  (BBL.one north);`.